# Python regex replace string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
string = 'C:/some path to mp3/song (7) title and so on (1).mp3'
```

should become:

```
C:/some path to mp3/song (7) title and so on.mp3
```

To match it i'm using the following regex:

```
pattern = '.*(\s\([0-9]+\))\.mp3'
```

And the match group contains: `(u' (1)',)`
however, when i'm trying to substitute the match like so:

```
processed = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

processed contains an empty string.
How can i get re.sub() to only replace the match found above?

Comment: Why use regex when all you need is `string.replace('(1)', '')` ?

Comment: @alfasin What if they want to match other number as well, like `'(2)'`?

Comment: @SethMMorton a. the question wasn't a general one. b. if it's only `(1)` and `(2)` I would still use a string replace ;)

Comment: @alfasin I think that one can assume if the OP used `[0-9]+`, they will be matching *any* integer, not just 1 or 2.

Comment: @alfasin I think the OP's point is to replace the `(###)` appended to duplicate filenames.  So the point is it happens right before the extension, not that it is a digit in parenthesis (hence the persisting `(7)` in the example).

Comment: @Sam and SethMMorton, yes that's exactly what i'm trying to do. Seems like it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were matching the entire string and replacing it, use a lookahead and only match the whitespace and `(1)` before the final extension.

**Expanded RegEx:**

```
\s*     (?# 0+ characters of leading whitespace)
\(      (?# match ( literally)
[0-9]+  (?# match 1+ digits)
\)      (?# match ) literally)
(?=     (?# start lookahead)
  \.    (?# match . literally)
  mp3   (?# match the mp3 extension)
  $     (?# match the end of the string)
)       (?# end lookeahd)
```

**Demo:** [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oA6nX6)

**Implementation:**

```
pattern = '\s*\([0-9]+\)(?=\.mp3$)'
processed = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

**Notes:**

- `mp3` can be replaced by `[^.]+` to match any extension or `(mp3|mp4)` to match multiple extensions.
- use `\s+` instead of `\s*` to require at least some whitespace before `(1)`, *thanks @SethMMorton*.

Comment: Based on the example, they might want `'\s+'` instead of `'\s*'`.